# JSP-Code is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit - Tomcat 9 Fix

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat9

I had to upgradefrom a Tomcat7 to Tomcat9 and raise a few frameworks.

"The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" 
is the error I'm getting.

I already tried the workaround, adding below code to the web.xml
Though it seems this is no longer working for Tomcat9.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>mappedfile</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Is there any way around this besides restructuring the file which is not an option for me.

Comment: Why isn't restructuring the file an option?

Comment: My assignment was to find another way to do this, of course if there is none, I will have to restructure. (Which might require more time)

Comment: Considering you only hit the method limit if you're writing code inside the JSP, which we all know is a bad idea, it might be useful to refactor the JSP anyway.

Comment: This is a classical example of technical debt: The interest is due and it's probably time to pay back at least some of it ...

Comment: It seems so, thank you for your responses! Just a bummer if it's not your debt, just your job to get rid of the interest being due..